# Getting line segment object from points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcobjects, c#, .net

I am fairly new to Arc Programming and am currently using .net to build my tool.

There is not much back ground information as I am starting from a Blank Map.  The goal of my tool is just to create a short cut (Hotkey) feature in order to place perpendicular lines.

I am attempting to use the function, [IConstructPoint2.ConstructPerpendicular()](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IConstructPoint_ConstructPerpendicular.htm) but it requires that I use `ISegment` as an input.

Prior to this, the only EVENT I am using to capture the points that I place on the map are [IEditEvents2.OnVertexAdded(IPoint)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IEditEvents2_OnVertexAdded.htm).  How can I capture the line segment that is constructed immediately after putting down a second point on the map?

Comment: Did you try casting [IEditSketch3.Geometry](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IEditSketch_Geometry.htm) to an `ISegmentCollection` and getting the first one?

Comment: Hey Kirk, This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the editor to `IEditSketch3`, then cast `IEditSketch3.Geometry` to an `ISegmentCollection`, and get the first segment.

Comment: I think the OP is after the last segment. From IEditSketch3 casting the Geometry to an IGeometryCollection (just in case of multiple parts), get the part (indexed by IEditSketch.Part), cast that part (IGeometry) to an ISegmentCollection then get the segment indexed by IEditSketch.Segment. Before this though you'll need to check the current part has *at least 2 points* by casting to IPointCollection and getting the PointCount, if == 1 then bail out.